# Is SVNAutoversioning directive in apache subversion imporant?

Tags: svn, apache, auto-versioning

If so why? I know setting this on will result in more number of automatically committed revisions. Is it good to have more auto commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this on to offer WebDav mappings, most OSes can make network mappings to http(s):// URLs.

If SVNAutoversioning is off, files cannot be saved to these mappings.